# VS is launching every time like first time

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Since I restore packages through VS Installer my VS Community is starting to launch like in first time with message sort of "We're getting things ready". What cause it might be?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running a Repair operting on VS 2017 through the setup program?

Comment: I did. Many times.